# Doctrine relation keep orphans

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I want to add a logging system to my Symfony backend to keep track of who does that. I will need a relation between my logg entity and my users entity.

From what i understand, foreign keys work in two ways, either prevent deletion of an entry if it is linked to another table item or cascade to remove orphans.

Is there a way to have a relation between two tables but keep the orphans ids in the table ?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you keep the foreign keys of deleted entries? This is a contraint violation.

Comment: To keep track of what happened even years ago. If one of the administrator removes a user, i still want to keep some track of what that user did.

Comment: Why not just use a bundle? This is already a solved problem so rather than investing time into creating your own logging/audit solution, it makes sense to just use an existing bundle such as https://github.com/DATA-DOG/DataDogAuditBundle Haven't looked into that bundle but it's top google result

Comment: Then, in my opinion, you'd better to implement the ability to disable an acount rather than deleting it. What's the point saving what the user with id 42 did if you have no other informations about him/her than the id? (disabling an account is easily done in Symfony)

Comment: Well, if i see that a user with id 42 did a lot of shitty things it'll be worth investigating by checking old database backups for example :)

Comment: I guess i could nullify the relation and add a message in plain text to keep a trace of what happened even if the user or concerned content has been removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a "SoftDelete", no ?

Add a property `deletedAt` that you update on remove event and when you query your relation you get only entities that have `deletedAt IS NULL`.

That way you keep the relations so you know which entities were related, etc.

I think there are some Bundles that does the SoftDelete thing.

Comment: I'm not going to do that because i don't want to rewrite a lot of things in my application but i guess that would be the better way so i'm going to validate your answer.

Comment: Moreover, beware soft user deletion may not be compliant to user data protection policies, or may require to erase or anonymize some fields when a user is soft deleted

Comment: Yeah removing/anonymizing address, email address, names, etc. should be done in the remove event too (or another AnonymizeEvent)